# Can any Javascript library be used with phonegap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I am trying to learn about Phonegap, and it is clear that any app can be developed by using exclusively web languages. However, I am wondering whether any javascript library could be used with it. For example, would something like Three.js work with it? What about bootstrap? Can I simply include it in the www folder, just as if it was a normal website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work, but it might be unstable depending on how complex they are; you need to test them to see if they work :) Idk about Three.js, but the naked Bootstrap libary (CSS and JS) has been working great with Cordova/PhoneGap.

Answer (score 4):

Phonegap uses `webview` control of each platfrom. For iOS it's safari based, android - android browser (chromium starting from kitkat - andoroid 4.4), and windows - IE. This means that normal `DOM exists` out-here. So basically yes - you may use libraries just as if it was a normal website.

However with phonegap you will still have some platform and browser differences and also using libraries that are developed for desktops may have a great performance impact on mobile.

For handling touch differences between the different platforms I would recommend using [HandJS](http://handjs.codeplex.com/) library.